# numpy.where - Weird behaviour: new elements spawning from nowhere?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to use numpy.where to remove [0,0,0] elements from an array. The test array has only one [0,0,0] element placed in the first position. It's shaped (800,3), so it should be (799,3) (after reshaping) or (2397,) after the selection. However the resulting array is (2937,).

My code:

```
array[np.where(array != [0,0,0])]
```

Is this some kind of bug?

P.D: dtype = 'uint8', in case it's useful.

Comment: While you are using `!=` wrong (as explained by user3483203), that wouldn't be enough to produce the results you describe. The result of your mistake should be to produce a result *smaller* than you expected, not bigger than your original array. There must be something else also going wrong.

Comment: what are the contents of the array and how do you define it?

Answer (score 2):

You are checking all elements in all columns, you need to use `all` along the first axis to find rows that are not all `0`:

```
(arr != 0).all(1)
```

---

```
>>> np.where((arr != 0).all(1))[0].shape
(799,)
```